# Scoring a line through certain Crystal Reports results

Tags: crystal-reports

Good Morning All,

Thank you for having a look at my question.

To start off, I am absolutely hopeless at Crystal Reports the program never does what I ask it to :). If you reply with an answer could put an answer in laymens terms that would be great thanks.

What I am hoping to achieve is for a line to be scored through centrally on every result that has a "YES" in the "Pict Exists" column.

Please see below images

This is what the report looks like
[image: 1. enter image description here]

This is the formula used to make it say either "YES" or "NO"
[image]

This is used to suppress duplicate results (which it does)
[image]

I don't know if you require any more information but other than the above images, there isn't anything out of the norm with this report.

If you need me to answer any questions just ask, I don't think I will be much help though.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the actual formula code?  For some reason, images aren't showing this morning for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

- Right-click the **PicExists** column
- Select "Format Field..."
- Go to the "Font" tab
- You should see "Strikeout" under the "Effects" section; click the formula button next to it
- I can't see your images for some reason so I don't know your formula name, but enter `{@YourFormulaName} = "Yes"` in the formula editor (using your real formula name) and save it.

The field should now have a line through it for any instances of "Yes".

Comment: It isn't exactly the look I wanted to achieve, but it does score a line through the individual results so it does do its job. Thank you